# How do I test whether a variable is an integer value in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to determine whether a variable is an integer or not.

I have a variable called arg2 and I need to determine whether arg2 is an integer. If arg2 is not an integer then it will set the value to 0.

How would I determine whether arg2 is an integer or not?

Comment: `isinstance(arg2, int)`?

Comment: Do you want to check if `arg2` has *type* `int`, or is a number whose value is or is close enough to an integer?

Comment: i want to know if it has type int

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can test arg2 type this way:

```
if (type(arg2) != int):
    arg2=0
```